# One-way linked list in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I started working on algorithms and data structures. I decided to have a try with one-way linked list. It contains functions like inserting element after chosen element, deleting element with given value and returning an amount of deleted items, function returning current content of list and class to write and read on/from files. There's a small problem with fuction which has to add new element. The debugger returns a following error:

First-chance exception at 0x00e71ea2 in AiSD.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Unhandled exception at 0x00e71ea2 in AiSD.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Looks like a problem with pointer but I have no idea how to solve it. It's not my speciality right now... Yet! So I asked you to help me. There is a code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    Node *next;
    int key;
};

class List
{
public:
    Node *head;
    unsigned int counter;

    List()
    {
        head = NULL;
        counter = 0;
    }

    unsigned size(Node *p)
    {
        unsigned int c=0;

        while(p)
        {
            c++;
            p = p->next;
        }
        return c;
    }


    void Addafter(Node *e, int v)
    {
    Node *p = new Node;
    p->next = e->next; //there's a problem
    p->key = v;
    e->next = p;
    }   

    int Delete(int v)
    {
        Node *p = new Node;
        int count = 0;
        while(p->next != NULL)
        {
            if(p->key = v)
            {
                delete p;
                count++;
                return count;
            }
        }
    }
    void Write()
    {
        string data;
        fstream file;
        file.open("D:\\plik2.txt", ios::out);
        Node *p = head;
        while(p->next != NULL)  
        {
            p = p->next;
            int wartosc = p->key;
            file<<wartosc;
        }
        file.close();
    }

    void Read()
    {
        string data;
        fstream file;
        file.open("D:\\plik.txt", ios::in);
        Node *p = head;
        for(int i=0; i<counter; i++)
        {
            getline(file, data);
            int result = atoi(data.c_str());
            p->key = result;
            p = p->next;
        }
        file.close();
    }


};

int main()
{
    List a;
    a.Read();
    a.Addafter(a.head, 3);
    a.Delete(5);
    a.size(a.head);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you indicate what language you're using by adding it to the title and tagging it in the categories please?

Comment: Questions like "Here is some code, fix my bugs" is not a good fit for the Stackoverflow Q&A format. You have to narrow it down to a specific question, and if you still do not get it when you have found the faulty line - search through old answers about Access Violation when using pointers. (In general, do not dereference a pointer before you have assigned it an address of an object that you own).

Comment: @MichałHabigier Select an answer and validate it so this post doesn't lie around and stay like this. Answer your own question with a final, correct answer if need be. But wrap this up please. :-)

Answer (score 1):

a.head is NULL when you enter the AddAfter method. So what happens is :

```
addAfter(Node *e /*Null in this case*/, int v) {
    Node *p = new Node; // Ok.
    p->next = e->next; // It is equivalent to p = NULL->next Which just segfaults.

}
```

In that case you're probably wanting to do :

```
addAfter(Node *e /*Null in this case*/, int v) {
        Node *p = new Node;
        p->key = v;
        if (e) {
            p->next = e->next; 
            e->next = p;
        }
        else {
            e = p;
            e->next = NULL;
        }

}
```

Whenever you're doing linked lists, take out a piece of paper and draw down what your code is doing step by step (Little boxes and arrows represent linked lists fine and lets you lay it out so it's understandable/visible to a human eye.)

Comment: It shed a new light on me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MichałHabigier If it's pointers, go with the `printf("%p", yourPointer)` technique. Figure out if they are NULL. And drawings. :3 Sounds a bit weird but helped me when i started off trying to understand linked lists. Also, if that answered your question, mark as an answer so the post is considered closed. :)